# Bootstrap Tooltip working but hidden due to z-index?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you hover over the first pencil, you can see the tooltip coming up but it's hidden.

How can I tell all tooltips to show up above everything else?

## Relevant code

```
$('.nav-text').on('click', null, function () {
    alert('heyo');
});
$('.nav-text').tooltip({
    'placement': 'right',
        'title': 'heyo'
});
```

## Complete example

```js
$('.down').click(function() {
  var $move = $('.side-study-box ul');
  $move.css({
    top: '-=20px'
  })
})

$('.up').click(function() {
  var $move = $('.side-study-box ul');
  $move.css({
    top: '+=20px'
  })
})


$('.nav-text').on('click', null, function() {
  alert('heyo');
});
$('.nav-text').tooltip({
  'placement': 'right',
  'title': 'heyo'
});
```

```css
.side-study-box {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 160px;
  display: table !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

.side-study-box .viewport {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.side-study-box span {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.side-study-box textarea {
  position: relative;
  height: 195px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  resize: none;
}

.side-study-box i {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

.side-study-box .side-box-menu {
  border-right: 1px solid #335987;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.side-box-menu-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3D6AA2;
  color: white;
}

.side-box-menu-nav:hover {
  background-color: #335987 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.side-study-box ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #335987;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.side-study-box ul li {
  margin: 0px;
}

.side-study-box ul li :hover {
  color: black;
}

.side-study-box ul li a {
  padding-left: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  color: gray;
}

.side-study-box ul li a .side-box-menu-control {
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="span4 side-study-box">
  <div class="side-box-menu"> <a class="side-box-menu-nav up"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i></a>

    <div class='viewport'>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-facetime-video "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-headphones "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control nav-text"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><a class="side-box-menu-nav down"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just set the tooltip position to `fixed`, like this:

```
.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
}
```

See [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvfFv/5/)

Comment: Or you could use the `container: 'body'` option existent in bootstrap tooltip.

Comment: position fixed is not a good idea because if the user scroll down the tooltip is not hided.

Comment: This is more a patch which works only in specific cases, and even in the "working demo" it doesn't work well if the page is scrolled.

Comment: @machineaddict your comment should be the selected answer

Answer (score 73):

Just set `data-container`.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title="first tooltip">
hover over me</a>
```

Comment: Best answer if you ask me. Clean data attribute, no extra jquery

Comment: Yeah, this one looks like the nicest one. using position: fixed does not feel natural.

Comment: This also fixed an issue if you are to place a Bootstrap tooltip inside a Kendo Grid.

Answer (score 33):

**Don't use `position: fixed`** for this, it looks like it works but will cause problems later on.

In your case, the best option would be to append the tooltip to the body (as mentionned by [@machineaddict in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863015/bootstrap-tooltip-working-but-hidden-due-to-z-index/36751293#comment47429643_16863182)) to **ensure it follows the pencil on scroll, which fixed positioning won't.**

```
$('.nav-text').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
        title: 'heyo',
    container: 'body' //<--- use the container option
});
```

You could even be more specific and use `container: '.side-study-box'` to ensure the tooltip follows its `div` even if the whole box scrolls independently from the body. Just make sure the container has `position: relative`.

As mentioned in [Diego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886799/1218980), you can use any option above as a *data* attribute:

```
<a class="nav-text" 
   data-toggle="tooltip" 
   data-container=".side-study-box" 
   data-placement="right" 
   title="heyo">
    ...
</a>
```

### Tooltip that Follows a div with overflow scroll

I added a `.container` div around the original snippet, made it small to force scrolling on overflow. You can see the tooltip follows the pencil icon when scrolling.

```js
$('.nav-text').click(function() {
  console.log('heyo');
}).tooltip({
  placement: 'right',
  title: 'heyo',
  // follows the box even if it is scrolled within the container div.
  container: '.container',
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
.side-study-box {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 160px;
  display: table !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}
.side-study-box .viewport {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.side-study-box span {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.side-study-box textarea {
  position: relative;
  height: 195px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  resize: none;
}
.side-study-box i {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
.side-study-box .side-box-menu {
  border-right: 1px solid #335987;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.side-box-menu-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3D6AA2;
  color: white;
}
.side-box-menu-nav:hover {
  background-color: #335987 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
.side-study-box ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #335987;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.side-study-box ul li {
  margin: 0px;
}
.side-study-box ul li :hover {
  color: black;
}
.side-study-box ul li a {
  padding-left: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  color: gray;
}
.side-study-box ul li a .side-box-menu-control {
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="span4 side-study-box">
    <div class="side-box-menu"><a class="side-box-menu-nav up"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i></a>
      <div class='viewport'>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-facetime-video "></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-headphones "></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control nav-text"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a class="side-box-menu-control"><i class="icon-hdd"></i></a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><a class="side-box-menu-nav down"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

This is best solution if you are using angular uib-bootstrap: Use dependency injection for $uibTooltipProvider, you can change the way tooltips and popovers behave by default; the attributes above always take precedence:

```
$uibTooltipProvider.options({
  appendToBody: true
});
```

Comment: UI Bootstrap library now provides an attribute tooltip-append-to-body for this purpose. The default is false, so I had to make the attribute true to make the tool tip visible when it overflows outside the parent.

Comment: This fixed it for me, I wan't this to be default behavior so I don't need another attribute to be added to everything.

Answer (score 0):

if we add the attribute container="body" into your html tag then it's not moving with html element on page scroll

Answer (score 0):

If building bootstrap (4.5) with npm (SASS), you can adjust `$zindex-tooltip` variable in your own variables.scss file.

in bootstrap 4.5 `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` @line 690

```
$zindex-tooltip:                    1070 !default;
```

BTW, you can find all variables in that file

Answer (score -1):

Position: Fixed !important; works here, but don't forget !important in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

just add the attribute `container="body"` into your html tag